Play analogue video from audio in
I have an adapter with AV input on one end and a 3.5 mm jack on the other.
Is it possible to plug the 3.5 mm jack into audio in and view the AV signal going in?
I've been trying to use the Analogue video capture device on VLC, but can't get it to read from audio in. Some answers to similar questions say that the physical hardware can't read the third channel, if that's the case, is there any way I could play video from one of the audio channel.

Audio channel is not video channel.

But wouldn't the analogue signal be readable regardless? What's the difference between the two?

Audio bandwidth ~20kHz. Analogue video bandwidth ~4.5 MHz, ~50x beyond audio! It would be like expecting to keep up with F1 race cars on a tricycle.

That's a shame. Thanks for clearing that up. Is it completely impossible, or does it work while looking terrible.

@jkozaka, it depends on the width of the bus: https://grist.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/alg_mark-malkoff1.jpg

Another factor is whether the drivers controlling the audio input on the computer can be manipulated to read a non-standard signal and pass it along into the system. But, perhaps telling us more about this adapter you have may give us more information. The TRS connector has a lot of variants that allow passing more than just 2 or 3 channels for audio. Finally, do not edit your post to say the problem is solved; that is not how this site works. An answer can be posted and you, as the asker, can mark that as the correct answer. This is the way we indicate answered questions on this site.

thanks for telling me about the edit.I was wondering how I mark something as solved.
the adapter is probably meant to output from the 3.5 mm jack and convert it to AV for video output.
The jack has 3 channels.

Is it meant for a specific capture card or device perhaps? Is there a model number or other identifier on the adapter? Can you include a picture of the adapter? What is the specific connector type of the other end?
